# Downloading Excel file in Angularjs and WebApi

Tags: angularjs, excel, export-to-excel

This succesfully downloads the file, however when I open the file excel complains saying it is corrupted and not saved in proper file format. I also tried using FIleSaver.js but no luck with it either. Same error. 
Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Server Code:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);    
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
fs.CopyTo(ms);
response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray());

response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileName = fileInfo.Name
};
return response
```

Client Side (AngularJS Service Code):

```
var req = {
    url: fpReportsWebAPIURL + 'api/Export/DownloadFile',
    method: 'POST',
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    //data: json, //this is your json data string
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    }
};

return $http(req).then(function (data) {
    var type = data.headers('Content-Type');
    var blob = new Blob([data], {
        type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    });
    saveAs(blob, 'helloAgain' + '.xlsx');
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?